# Makefile error No rule to make target when building docker image

Tags: bash, docker, makefile

I'm trying to learn to write my own Makefiles for docker automation.
I've read a bit about this subject and than tried to copy some example code I found online but it gives me an error. Any ideas?

```
$ make build
make: *** No rule to make target '-f', needed by 'build'.  Stop.

NS ?= test
VERSION ?= latest
IMAGE_NAME ?= test
CONTAINER_NAME ?= test
build:
    docker build -t $(NS)/$(IMAGE_NAME):$(VERSION) -f Dockerfile .

run:
    docker run -d --rm --name $(CONTAINER_NAME) $(NS)/$(IMAGE_NAME):$(latest)

default: build
```

Comment: You don't seem to be showing the part of your Makefile which defines a target `-f`

Comment: But its an option of ```docker build``` command. So you are saying I've defined my command to run on build incorrectly? What the correct form should be when the command to run is ```docker build -t test/test:latest -f Dockerfile .``` ?

Comment: First things first. Does your Makefile have a tab before each `docker` command?

Comment: Ok that explains it. Stupid mistake. My editor automatically replaces all tabs with 4 spaces. Now it works correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @tripleee for pointing out that spaces preceding my docker command should actually be a tab.

My editor was changing them to spaces automatically.